# When will Ember Data be out of beta?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, production-environment

I'm using Ember in a production site, and am considering adding Ember Data. However, I'm concerned that it's still in beta.

Does anyone know when we might expect a stable release?

I can't seem to find any roadmap or dates anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is an answer for an exact 1.0 release date but here is a blog post talking about the roadmap to Ember Data 1.0 http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/18/the-road-to-ember-data-1-0.html.

You can also use another persistence layer like EPF, Ember Model, Ember Restless or go like Discourse and role out your own.

There are apps that use ember data in production like, Skylight: that is built by Tilde.

You may run into bugs but just put in a Pull Request (PR) if you find a bug. But if you want to know more I would say going into the IRC channel for ember and asking in there for dates and such. And post code here on Stackoverflow for help.

Answer (score 5):

June 12, 2015.

At EmberConf 2015, Tom and Yehuda announced that Ember 2.0 and Ember Data 1.0 would be released on June 12 (in addition to at least beta 1.0 releases of Ember CLI, Ember Inspector, Liquid Fire, and List View). See the [section of their opening keynote about guaranteeing stability across the ecosystem and "lockstep SemVer"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o12-90Dm-Qs&list=PLE7tQUdRKcyacwiUPs0CjPYt6tJub4xXU&t=2284).

Ember Data 1.0 will also have support for the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org) spec out of the box, first class support for pagination and filtering, and of course access to the excellent existing adapter ecosystem.

There's no need to wait though. I would say that Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.15 is very stable and used in countless production systems. (Earlier pain points with relationships and having a "single source of truth" have been worked out.)